# Status Update using Nerilcrookes' OAuth extension to CakePHP HttpSocket returns "incorrect signature error"

Tags: cakephp, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm using Neilcrookes' OAuth extension to CakePHP HttpSocket ( http://www.neilcrookes.com/2010/04/12/cakephp-oauth-extension-to-httpsocket/ )

My request looks like:

```
Array ( 
    [method] => POST 
    [uri] => Array ( 
        [host] => api.twitter.com
        [path] => 1/statuses/update.json
    )
    [auth] => Array (
        [method] => OAuth
        [oauth_token] => xxx
        [oauth_token_secret] => xxx
        [oauth_consumer_key] => xxx
        [oauth_consumer_secret] => xxx
    )
    [body] => Array (
        [status] => Hello World
    )
)
```

I have the oauth_token and oauth_token_secret from the previous request from the user

response looks like `{“request”:”\/1\/statuses\/update.json”,”error”:”Incorrect signature”}`

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess: But could it be that your signature isn't correct?

Comment: Well yes, that's what the response says, but how do I correct it??

Comment: Finally! I got it .... It was a very stupid error.... I was retrieving the oauth_token_secret from the database but the it appears that the length of the field in my database was one short ....
Hence the incorrect signature